# Updating related table to AspNetUsers

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity, blazor

I created one to many relationship between AspNetUsers table and Order table to do that I inherit from IdentityUser. My application is using one individual user account authentication.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<Orders> Orders { get; set; }
}

    public class Orders
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

   
    private int OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }


}
```

How can I update the order table one a user is connected, maintaining the one-to-many relationship between AspNetUsers and order table?

NB i am using blazor,

Comment: blazor is not matter, you need to update order table by Entity Framework manually.

Answer (score 1):

If you want this to be done automatically, you need [EF Core Migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli).